# Trouble installing bbpress

Tags: bbpress

I'm trying to install bbpress 2.1 on wordpress 3.4.1 and I am running into some difficulties. When i try to go to /forums (which is my "Forums base" setting) I get a 404 page. I have tried resetting my permalinks. (set to default, saved, and set it back to %postname%) but no luck

The other problem I'm running into is that when bbpress is active my homepage starts using `page.php` instead of `index.php`. Completely puzzled on this one.